# How to use svelte to vertical fly in and out element

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-transition

I'm trying to animate the  tag. I want to make it fly from top to it's current position and and out to fly from it's current position to top.

```
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'

    let state = true
    function toggle(){
        state = !state
    }

</script>

<div style="margin-top:4rem;padding:2rem;background:lightgray">

    {#if state}
         <a transition:fly="{{ y: 200, duration: 250 }}" 
                on:click={toggle} href="#/link1">
                link1
         </a>
    {:else}
         <a transition:fly="{{ y: 200, duration: 250 }}" 
                on:click={toggle} href="#/link2">  
                link2
         </a>
    {/if}

</div>
```

I didn't understand quite well how transitions and animations work. In this case even if y it's 200 it goes on x axis.

[Here is a link to the svelte repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/0ebf64e0daa24faa834b641ee75ee349?version=3.31.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions in Svelte are done using CSS, in the case of `fly` this is through the use of the `transform` property. This is a property that can only be applied to *transformable elements*, you could read the [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transformable-element) or take as rule of thumb that only block level elements can be transformed. An anchor tag `<a>` is by default not a *block* but an *inline* element.

You can solve your problem by adding styling making the `<a>` tags block level either by setting `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.